# How to make the generated machine learning model satisfied with specified proportion

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, gan

If an image is composed of three categorical variables with fixed proportions (such as 0.2,0.3, and 0.5), how could I ensure the generated image (such as GAN model) is satisfied with this proportion?